# Transmission: permission denied on USB disk

Tags: linux, permissions, usb-storage, transmission

I have Raspberry Pi running RaspBMC with a WD MyBook connected using USB. The drive is automatically mounted to /media/My Book. I have created a folder /media/My Book/downloads and I have set Trasmission's download directory to be /media/My Book/downloads.

When I try to download a file, Transmission says

```
Error: Permission denied (/media/My Book/downloads/The.Simpsons.S24E09.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION [PublicHD]/The.Simpsons.S24E09.720p.HD
```

ls -la gives me

```
drwx------ 1 pi       0 Dec 15 16:24 downloads
```

So I guess the problem is that transmission runs under different user than pi and cannot write to the folder. However when I execute

```
chmod -R 777 downloads
```

the operations succeeds without any error but the permissions do not change, they stay 700 just for the owner.

What am I doing wrong and how can I enabled Transmission to write to that directory? It is a NTFS drive, df -T says

```
/dev/sda1  fusebulk
```

Comment: Try `chmod -R 777 downloads`.

Comment: Hey Igor, I am just mentioning this in a comment since it is off topic of your request, but just a nudge as it sounds you're learning a ton!  Double check your understanding of system permissions, "777" would be r/w/x for **all** Owner, Group AND Other (respectively).  So the owner maintains "7" permissions (read, write, execute).  Wikipedia has a good summary [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Numeric_notation).

Comment: @Scott tried that, it is in my post

Comment: @Igor - The location of `-R` is important.

Comment: @nerdwaller I understand the permissions, I just do not know why it does not work. Maybe because it is a NTFS drive, some parameters for automounting must be set? As user Pi I have no problem writing to the dir (of coursem because oif the drwx)

Comment: You order are arguments in typing the wrong the.

Comment: @nerdwaller no change, still 700 (drwx------)

Comment: Why not try on the one folder first, with sudo.  `sudo chmod 770 downloads`  See what happens.  Then add the `transmission` user to your usergroup, whatever you're in.  That is a little more secure.  Otherwise, you can change the transmission user in the config files (here: `/home/transmission/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json`).

Comment: You are being very confusing.  You say you are giving the output from `ls –la`, but I don’t see `.` and `..`.  You say “the permissions … stay 777 just for the owner” (what does that mean?) but then later you say “still 700”.

Comment: @Scott I am giving just the relevant line of the listing for the downloads directory, not for the whole disk. Your are right, there was a error in my question, the permissions stay 700 after running chmod 777, and sudo chmod 777

Comment: Try mounting the mybook elsewhere, to see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- Check if you have installed the driver "ntfs-3g" to have access privileges to read and write NTFS partition.

2.- Edit the file / etc / fstab / and add the following line, depending on the type of usb disk.

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/ntfs-3g download default 0 0
```

3.- Mount USB disk with the command:

```
$mount / media / download
```

4.- Run Transmission